# Android support action bar

Tags: android

I'm trying to add the support action bar to my Android app, but right at the start where I have

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

I get an error `No resource found that matches the given name: android:Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

I can import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` and `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` so I think I've added the support libraries correctly. Why do Android dev docs gloss over this? It should be Lesson #1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

`android:Theme.AppCompat.Light` is incorrect. Everything with the namespace 'android' refers to properties from the framework ( but `Theme.AppCompat.Light` only exists in the support library).